# C# Entity Framework not initializing database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a WPF database-based application with EF code-first. I had a problem of a not generated database, that I tried to solve like this:

```
using (var db = new MyDBContext())
{
    db.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

I've inserted this code in `App.xamls.cs`, overriding `OnStartup` method (this works).

Then I tried to seed some default data like this:

```
public class MyDBContextSeeder : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDBContext context)
    {
        IList<Dog> defaultDog = new List<Dog>();
        defaultDog.Add(new Dog("Spike"));

        foreach (Dog d in defaultDog)
            context.Dogs.Add(d);

        // more data here....

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

And, since I'm using a custom initializer, I've changed my the first code above like this:

```
using (var db = new PizzeriaDBContext())
{
    new MyDBContextSeeder().InitializeDatabase(db);    //this line
    db.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

The problem now is:

- when I build my application my default data is not inserted. I'm really sure of that.
- if I try to build my application again, I have an exception like:

  > Dog entity is already in database.

Migrations are enabled.

I already tried to delete `db.Database.Initialize(true)`, but when I do this, my database it's not even created.

Comment: Did you do an Add-Migration or have automatic migrations enabled?  The seed method only runs on migration.

Comment: @mrsargent do you mean the `InitialCreate : DbMigration` class generated when you type Add-Migration in Console? If so, yes. and I also have             `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` in `Configuration.cs`

Comment: What is your database connection string? `if I try to build my application again, I have an exception like: Dog entity is already in database` looks to me like it's going somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: @Tom I don't think that is the problem, because the database it is created and I can see it. By the way :   `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Cw2.MyDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Cw2.MyDBContext;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>`

Comment: If you set `db.Database.Initialize(true)` to `db.Database.Initialize(false)`, do you still get the error `Dog entity is already in database.`?

Comment: @Tom I just realize that I get this error when I manually delete my database from SQL Server Management Studio (even if I close existing connections)

Answer (score 0):

By default your database is using the **CreateDatabaseIfNotExits** Initializer.  That is why you are getting your exception.  So i think what you need to do is the following:

On your overriden OnStartup you can use

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext,Configuration>)
```

For this to work you need to change your Configuration.cs class from **internal sealed to Public**

For reference you can look at the very bottom of this article
[MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Comment: It' giving me an error on your code: underlining Configuration and saying it doesn't exist

Comment: and you changed the Configuation class from internal sealed to public?

Comment: yes, I fixed it, don't worry. But do I have to add this part inside `using (var db = new MyDBContext())
{
}` and substitute the code I already have inside?

Comment: if I substitute my `new MyDBContextSeeder().InitializeDatabase(db);` with your code it's not creating the database at all.

Comment: Did you say in the comment above that you deleted the database with SQL management studio?  The MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion only work on a previous created database.  If the database doesn't exists you will need to use the default CreateDatabaseIfNotExists

Comment: Yes, It is when I get this error. I try to delete the database because I need to see if my application creates it or not, because I had this problem (actually, as I said in the comment above, if I remove new MyDBContext... database it is not created). Where do I use CreateDatabaseIfNotExists? And why I still don't have any data inside the database even if it is created?

Comment: You can put it in the Onstartup method but if like but you really don't have to put anything because that is configuration the entityframework uses by default.

Comment: This is my problem...If I don't put anything, my database it is not created. I have to froce it to be created. And, when I force it, my data is not inserted inside it